# Mismatch error while running macro in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am running a macro that converts hexadecimal code to M68000 programming language. However, I am receiving the error message

> 'type mismatch'.

Here is the relevant code. I am receiving the error on the last line.

```
Dim hxad As String
Dim hx As Long
Dim rnga As Range
Set rnga = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range
hxad = Mid(rnga.Text, 1, (InStr(rnga.Text, Chr(13)) - 1)
Set rnga = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(par).Range
hx = CInt("&H" & Mid(hxad, 3, 4))
```

I have been able to run the code flawlessly before but now, all of sudden, I am unable to run it, even after I did not change anything.

Can someone please give me tips to resolve this issue?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Does `rnga ` have a value after you set it? If so, what is the value of `rnga.Text`? (You can use `Debug.Print rnga.Text` after you set it to find out)  - next, what is the value of `hxad`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a type mismatch error, this means that either your input is not defined by what you are trying to find. Since your program was working before, this time you may have accidentally entered a character that you have not defined.

Comment: Thank you! I had accidentally left the memory addresses in the code.